# MVC dropdownlist onchange event not calling properly the action in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, onchange

Hi all I need to do here is that when the selection is changed of a dropdown list, with the use of AJAX I want to call an action and pass some data. Here below you can find The code that I am using. I have searched a lot and dont get why it is not entering in the action. The data and url are correct. The Controller name is HomeController and the action name is getData.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {
        var a = document.getElementById("tournaments");
        var datad = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
        var url = '/Home/getData';
        var completeurl = window.location.host + url;

        alert(completeurl);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: completeurl,
            data: {tournamentid : datad},
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) { alert('got here with data'); },
            error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
        });
        };

</script>

Dropdownlist:
 <%: @Html.DropDownList("tournaments", null, new { name = "tournaments", title = "Please Select Tournament.", onchange = "submitform();",id = "tournaments"}) %>

Action:
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getData(int? tournamentid)
    {
        //perform your action here
        UserBl us = new UserBl();
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(tournamentid);
        Tournament tour = us.GetTournamentById(num);
        return Json(tour, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you would do it like this:

```
$(function(){   // document and jquery ready
       $("#tournaments").on("change", function(e){
              var dropValue = $(this).val();

               $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/getData/' + dropValue,
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) { alert('got here with data'); },
        error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
    });
        });
 });
```

Comment: Still no responce :/ Do i need to change something in the global.asax with the  routes.MapRoute? Anyway many thanks for your help

Comment: not too sure,  think maybe you need to find out why?  it did not do something, like in your console, see the transfer of data, see if the request even happens,  what was the error, is it route based or 500 based

Comment: console is f12 on IE, and F12 on chrome

Comment: it is giving me that "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: solved that error now its giving me this new one "Uncaught ReferenceError: intellisense is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways
one is  (use selectedItem as tournamentId)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tournaments").change(function () {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        submitform(selectedItem);
    });
});</script>
```

Or 
put *javascript:* for onchange attribute

```
onchange = "javascript:submitform();"
```

EDITED : 
for that I would suggest

```
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: "GET",
url: url,
data: { "tournamentid ": datad},
success: function (data) {
    alert("succeded")
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('Failed ');
}});
```

Comment: I have updated suggestion for getData, now u can put break-point at action and check whether its being called or not

Comment: for the `$.ajax()` method, do I just put it within the `@Scripts{<script> </script> }` block (if I am using a view layout), or do I have to call it from `onchange`?